# acquireTokenSilent with angular and microsoft msal fails with AADB2C90077 / AADB2C90205

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Im trying to get token from AAD B2C configuration using angular9 and microsoft/msal

My module configuration looks like this;

```
MsalModule.forRoot(
            {
                auth: {
                    clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    authority:
                        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/isthereanynewscodeblast.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_itansignup",
                    validateAuthority: false,
                },
                cache:{
                    cacheLocation:"localStorage",
                    storeAuthStateInCookie:true
                }
            }
        ),
```

This is used for loggining in and this works. Im able to get basic information like this:
[image]

Next once logged im trying to get more data for graph data or for my custom scopes, like this:

```
getToken() {
        const accessTokenRequest = {
             scopes: [
                 "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read",
            //     // "https://isthereanynewscodeblast.onmicrosoft.com/05cd7635-e6f4-47c9-a5ce-8ec04368b297/application_reader",
            //     // "https://isthereanynewscodeblast.onmicrosoft.com/05cd7635-e6f4-47c9-a5ce-8ec04368b297/application_writer",
             ],
            clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/isthereanynewscodeblast.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_itansignup",
            redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200",
            // postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
        };
        this.authService
            .acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("acquireTokenPopup");
                this.token = res.accessToken;
                this.getUser();
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log("acquireTokenPopup catch");
                console.log(e);
            });
    }
```

Acquiring token fails with following error:

```
InteractionRequiredAuthError: AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'.
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong or where to look for answers:

- my scopes looks solid (^C^V - names and links)
- I tried changing user flow session behavior to disabled
- Changed `acquireTokenPopup` returns this error:

  `ServerError: AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the microsoftonline.com URL in B2C is deprecated ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin#deprecation-of-loginmicrosoftonlinecom)).
You should use something like this as your authority:

```
`https://${tenant}.b2clogin.com/${tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/${policyId}`
```

Also, it is not currently possible to access MS Graph API on behalf of a B2C user.
So you should not specify MS Graph API scopes.
You should be able to specify a scope for an API you have registered as a B2C app:

```
app.acquireTokenSilent({ scopes: ['api-client-id/ScopeName'] });
```

Or if you want an id token, you can specify the client id:

```
app.acquireTokenSilent({ scopes: [clientId] });
```