# Failing prompt parameter=none-B2C custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Issue statement:

The session should be present in Azure b2c as the session timeout is configured as 86400 seconds(1 day) in the custom policy “error=interaction_required&error_description=AADB2C90077%3a+User+does+not+have+an+existing+session+and+request+prompt+parameter+has+a+value+of+%27None%27.”

meaning user should be able to authenticate without prompting for interactions but it is not.

On the fiddler trace, there is no error returned

Comment: Please any help would be well appreciated as why the prompt parameter still doesn't work on my policy. I have confirmed my redirect Url and scope are properly configured but yet issue is still thesame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with the following points:

1. Please check if tenant Id value is correctly given without a mistake
   and check if correct scopes are given. If it is to call a web api
   make sure to provide complete scope  this way:

   `https://{tenantname or id}.onmicrosoft.com/api/read`
2. Please check if you are trying to call microsof t graph api with
   scope for it. see [AADB2C90077 - Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148741/acquiretokensilent-with-angular-and-microsoft-msal-fails-with-aadb2c90077-aadb) which says graph api cant be accessed by b2c /local
   only users ,as graph API is  accessible for standard Azure AD  users
   or applications.
3. It may also be due to `session expiry`.So after setting the expiry
   or token life time also try changing lifetimes  access token ,
   refresh token .Try to reauthenticate / let the user login as it
   initially tries to get cached token.
4. Try to get a token non interactive way try silent calls with
   acquireTokenSilent.

   ```
   this.application
       .acquireTokenSilent('https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/api/read')
   ```

[msal-js nteractive request-prompt-behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-prompt-behavior)

4. As a part of workaround try to turn on the block-third party cookies
   for the browser to make sure not to block third-party cookies and
   check again.Disable later if not required.

**References:**

1. [prerequisites to use MS Graph API, and interact with resources in your Azure AD B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations#prerequisites)
2. [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267456/cannot-renew-access-token-from-b2c-error-aadb2c90077)